# Подскажите, каким образом делаются алерты, которые при каком-то событии отображаются в нижней части окна, прилипая к нему?

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование

Подскажите, каким образом делаются алерты, которые при каком-то событии отображаются в нижней части окна, прилипая к нему и не пропадая при прокруте?

Comment: Создаёшь дивчик, лепишь куда надо с `position: fixed; display: none`, по наступлении какого-нибудь события отображаешь.

Comment: А это будет работать, если допустим страница имеет высоту в 1000px, при этом пользователь видит всего первые 500px. Если я в самом низу сделаю такой div, то юзер его увидит находясь в самом начале страницы?

Comment: Вот [тут](http://htmlbook.ru/css/position) есть про позиционирование. Рекомендую к прочтению.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function removeAlert(){
    var GetLastAlert = $('.alerts .alert').last();
    setTimeout(function(){GetLastAlert.slideUp(500);}, 4000);
    setTimeout(function(){GetLastAlert.remove();}, 4500);
}

function sendAlert(type, message){
    switch (type) {
        case 'green': break;
        case 'yellow': break;
        case 'red': break;
        default: type = 'green'; break;
    }

    $(".alerts").append(
        "<div class='alert " + type + "' role='alert'>" +
            "<p>" + message + "</p>" +
        "</div>"
    );
    removeAlert();
}

$('button').on('click', function(){
  var type = $(this).attr('data-color');
  sendAlert(type, 'Message');
});
```

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica , sans-serif;
}

main{
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
button{
  margin: 0 5px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  background-color: transparent;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
button:hover{
  color: #fff;
}
button.green:hover{
  background-color: #2ecc71;
}
button.yellow:hover{
  background-color: #f1c40f;
}
button.red:hover{
  background-color: #e74c3c;
}

.alerts{
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-end;
  padding: 20px;
}
.alert{
  background-color: #e74c3c;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}

.alert.green{
  background-color: #2ecc71;
}
.alert.yellow{
  background-color: #f1c40f;
}
.alert.red{
  background-color: #e74c3c;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main>
  <button data-color="green" class="green">Green !</button>
  <button data-color="yellow" class="yellow">Yellow !</button>
  <button data-color="red" class="red">Red !</button>
</main>

<div class="alerts"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Как верно написал Alex Sazonov в комментарии к вопросу, необходимо использовать свойство [css](/questions/tagged/css) - `position: fixed;`. Отображение блока возможно выполнить с помощью [js](/questions/tagged/js) несколькими способами.

К примеру так:

```js
function showHide(element_id) {
      var obj = document.getElementById(element_id); 
      
      if (obj.style.display != "block") 
          obj.style.display = "block";
      else obj.style.display = "none";  
}
```

```css
.layer1 {
    background: #f0f0f0;
    height: 2000px;
}

.layer2 {
    position: fixed;
    color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: green;
    bottom: 0px; /* Положение от нижнего края */
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="layer1">
      Это содержимое страницы высотой 2000 px на сером фоне.
      <br>
      <input type="button" value="Показать/Скрыть сообщение" onclick="showHide('message')"/>
</div>
<div id="message" class="layer2">
      Тут фиксированное по нижнему краю сообщение с зеленым фоном.
</div>
```